# migrating SQL logins to segregated environments

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-migration

I am currently migrating our SQL Server and all databases to a new sandbox environment. For this new environment, there is no network connectivity to the QA or Prod SQL servers. There is also no possibility to enable connectivity.

I have already migrated the databases and the AD accounts however I cannot recreate the SQL logins since there are a lot of logins and I do not know the passwords.

Are there any suggestions or steps I could use to migrate these SQL login accounts?

Previously I used sql tools from dbatools to use powershell to migrate these accounts but since there is no connectivity between the environments this would not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: This might be better in scope of ServerFault -forum. More sysadmin stuff than coding.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the sandbox environment have the same passwords?  Also here's how to [Transfer logins and passwords between instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances).